# How do Timer event handlers work in .Net? Are they preemptive?

Tags: c#, winforms, timer

I have a WinForm timer with a short interval (33 ms).

I have other code in my app that enables and disables this timer.

In the timer event handler, is it necessarily true that timer.Enabled = true? Or is it possible that by the time the handler starts to execute, another piece of the code may have disabled the timer?

Comment: Interested in the context of hunting down possible race conditions.

Comment: Setting the timer.Enabled = false does not stop execution of the code that is running in the handler.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> is it necessarily true that timer.Enabled = true?

Yes.  The only way the Tick event can be raised is when your UI thread goes idle and is no longer executing any code.  It then re-enters the dispatcher loop to wait for another notification.  If there is any code that disables the timer then that code necessarily has to run *before* your UI thread goes idle.  Since everything is synchronous, you have a hard guarantee that Tick won't fire anymore.

It is technically valid to stop the timer on a worker thread.  But of course you then no longer have a decent execution order guarantee anymore.  Starting the timer on a worker is not valid and won't come to a good end, it simply won't tick.

Beware of System.Timers.Timer, its Elapsed event runs on a threadpool thread and may have been scheduled to execute before you disabled it.  It still runs.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed answer.